# SFML atan2 function and deceleration

Tags: c++, sfml, trigonometry, acceleration, atan2

```
if(wIsPressed){
    movement.x += sin((player.getRotation() * 3.141592654)/ 180) * .5; //accelerates ship at a rate of 0.5 ms^2
    movement.y -= cos((player.getRotation() * 3.141592654)/ 180) * .5; //accelerates ship at a rate of 0.5 ms^2

}
else if(abs(movement.x) > 0 || abs(movement.y) > 0){
    double angle = (atan2(movement.x, movement.y) * 3.141592654) / 180; //finds angle of current movement vector and converts fro radians to degrees


    movement.x -= sin((angle)) * 0.5; //slows down ship by 0.5 using current vector angle
    movement.y += cos((angle)) * 0.5; //slows down ship by 0.5 using current vector angle



}
```

basically, what happens after using this code is that my ship is pulled directly down to the bottom of the screen, and acts like the ground has gravity, and i dont understand what i am doing incorrectly

Comment: You're not converting your angle to degrees properly. It should be: double angle = atan2(movement.x, movement.y) * 180 / 3.141592654;

Comment: does atan2 return radians or degrees?

Comment: All of the trig functions expect and return radians.

Comment: because my acceleration code wroks, but my deceleration code does not

Comment: double angle = (atan2(movement.x, movement.y) * 180) / 3.141592654;

Comment: this causes the ship to move to the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment:

You're not converting your angle to degrees properly. It should be:

```
double angle = atan2(movement.x, movement.y) * 180 / 3.141592654;
```

However, you're using this angle in another trig calculation, and the C++ trig functions expect radians, so you really shouldn't be converting this to degrees in the first place. Your **else if** statement could also be causing problems, because you're checking for an absolute value greater than 0. Try something like this:

```
float angle = atan2(movement.x, movement.y);
const float EPSILON = 0.01f;

if(!wIsPressed && abs(movement.x) > EPSILON) {
    movement.x -= sin(angle) * 0.5;
}
else {
    movement.x = 0;
}

if(!wIsPressed && abs(movement.y) > EPSILON) {
    movement.y += cos(angle) * 0.5;
}
else {
    movement.y = 0;
}
```

Comment: when i make this change, the ship moves to te bottom of the screen, then drifts back to the top again

Comment: It worked! the only thing i had to change was: movement.y += cos(angle) * 0.5; to movement.y -= cos(angle) * 0.5; and the epsilon value to 0.4f